Import dataset from a datetime library in Jupyert notebook ide
How could I import a dataset from a datetime library? Using dt = shortcut for dataset and removing the header row using list slicing? ( this one it's more easy)
So far this is the code to import a dataset = 'Applestore.csv' in jupyter notebook ide
import datetime as dt
from dt import dataset 
dataset='AppleStore.csv'

I tried using import  from, converting datatime, give modules a value, etc
